# How would you improve this Julia code?

Tags: python, performance, julia

```
seqs = Set{String}()
for ln in eachline(STDIN)
    if ln[1] == '@'
        println(ln)
        continue
    end
    seq = split(ln)[10]
    if !(seq in seqs)
        println(ln)
        push!(seqs,seq)
    end
end
```

It is much slower (5x) than the Python version below, why is that? Note: **seq** contains only ASCII letters.

```
import sys

seqs = set()
for ln in sys.stdin:
    if ln.startswith('@'):
        print ln,
        continue
    seq = ln.split()[9]
    if not seq in seqs:
        print ln,
        seqs.add(seq)
```

Comment: Put it in a function.

Comment: to understand what Chris meant you could look at [doc](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips.html#man-performance-tips-1).

Comment: Julia also have a `startswith`; `startswith(ln, '@')` is the same as: `ln[1] == '@'`

Comment: note to @Gatozee: if Simon's answer below helps you, then please accept it!

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I tried to put things in a function as @Simon Byme does, but that didn't help. Then I tested with only "seq = split(ln)[10]" in the loop and nothing else. It turns out the single operation takes about half of the total time. I suspect Julia's string is not efficient, maybe because it needs to deal with Unicode. Is there a string type that can only process ASCII? In my case, I have no need for Unicode.

Comment: Consider reformulating and posting this question to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), which I think is a better site for this kind of question.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestions from the comments give:

```
function foo()
    seqs = Set{String}()
    for ln in eachline(STDIN)
        if startswith(ln, '@')
            println(ln)
            continue
        end
        seq = split(ln)[10]
        if !(seq in seqs)
            println(ln)
            push!(seqs,seq)
        end
    end
    return seqs
end
```

A possibly faster variant which relies on the fact that `Set` is internally just a `Dict`:

```
function foo()
    seqs = Set{String}()
    for ln in eachline(STDIN)
        if startswith(ln, '@')
            println(ln)
            continue
        end
        seq = split(ln)[10]
        get!(seqs.dict, seq) do
            println(ln)
            nothing
        end
    end
    return seqs
end
```